# Solving $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-it}\prod_{k=1}^n(e^{2kit}-1)dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve this integral:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-it}\prod_{k=1}^n(e^{2kit}-1)dt$$
I tried working on the product as $\ln P$ on this form:
$$\ln P=\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(e^{2kit}-1)$$
but it didn't lead to anywhere.
If anyone has some indications or even an answer, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @ClementYung solving the product / writing it in a simpler form

Comment: There's nothing to solve, since $P$ is defined to be that product. What do you mean by "simpler form"?

Comment: Is $2kt$ the exponent of $e$ or just $2k$ ?

Comment: @ClementYung the product being written as something that can be manipulated easier, maybe a sum or something else

Comment: @pooja sorry for the typo. Corrected

Comment: Do you want to determine $t$ for a given $P$? If yes, edit your question.

Comment: @PaulFrost I'm trying to solve $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-it}\prod_{k=1}^n(e^{2kt}-1)dt$ and I guess I need a simple form of the product above

Comment: Then add your comment to your question.

Comment: From where do you have this integral and what makes you think there's a closed form for it? I bet there isn't a decent one, unless you made a typo in that product.

Comment: Indeed there's a typo, add an $i$ in the exponent of the product and you get the answer to be $0$.

Comment: @Nyssa you're right. Sorry for the typo! How do you came to the conclusion that the answer is 0?

Comment: I solved it or atleast I think I did so. As a hint, use the residue theorem.

Comment: This post keeps on changing. Is this the definite version? If this is it indeed the answer is zero (no need for residuum theorem)

Comment: @Icv yes, this is the definite version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple proof. First note that

$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} e^{it m} dt = 2 \pi \,\delta_{m,0} \ \quad \mathrm{for } \ \  m\in\mathbb{Z} \ \ \ \ \ (1)
$$

Now note that, with $x=e^{it}$

$$
P = \prod_{k=1}^n (x^{2k} -1)
$$

is a polynomial in $x$ with *only even powers* . In particular in $P$ there is no term proportional to $x$. This means that in  $e^{-it} \prod_{k=1}^n (e^{2ikt}-1)$ there is no constant term.

As a consequence, using the result (1) we get

$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} e^{-it } \prod_{k=1}^n (e^{2ikt}-1) dt = 0
$$